# Creating Facebook event for specific page with FB Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need synchronize events from my CMS to Facebook specific page. I'm trying to create an event for my created page but still have no result. I can simply create events, related to user, but not to page. Code uses [Facebook PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).

```
$page_id = '31337';
$page = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}");
$event_data = array(
    'name'          => 'Event: ' . date("H:m:s"),
    'start_time'    => time() + 60*60,
    'end_time'      => time() + 60*60*2,
    'owner'         => $page
);
$post = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}/events", 'POST', $event_data);
```

After executing this snippet, event is created but as I've said before it belongs to user though 'owner' in given data is page. My app has manage_pages, create_event and publish_stream permissions. What I'm missing?

**Solution**

At ["OLD REST API"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create) documentation I have found that "new Graph API" still needs parameter **page_id**. So variable $event_data should be like below:

```
$event_data = array(
    'name'          => 'Event: ' . date("H:m:s"),
    'start_time'    => time() + 60*60,
    'end_time'      => time() + 60*60*2,
    'page_id'       => $page['id]
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You just helped me out! :)

Answer (score 3):

«Creates an event on behalf of the user if the application has an active session key for that user; otherwise it creates an event on behalf of the application.» — [Source](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thx for answer, but actually not. When user is not logged in, event is created at the app's page. But not at specific page, which id I have.

Comment: But in your given link I have found the solution: "The page_id argument can be used to generate events for groups and Pages.". Its strange that "new graph API" documentation lacks info about page_id parameter which is described at "Old REST API".

Comment: Great then :) Facebook's documentation is far from decent, as you probably know by now...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the access token of the managed page, which you can get from graph.facebook.com/me/account (of course passing your access token to get the list of fan pages you manace). You will see there a list of access tokens for each of your fan pages, use those to create events or post to your fanpage.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting- my experience is exactly the opposite. I tried creating the event with the page_id parameter and got a Permissions Error. Removed the page_id and it worked fine. The trick was to use the application access token rather than user one.

Comment: You must set list of permissions to your application. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions The 'manage_pages' permission is actually what you need.

Comment: Not as such- my pages are created by my app rather than a user, so there is no manage_pages permission involved. For some reason, specifying page_id caused the API call to fail, removing it got it to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set the access_token to the page one before making the post. Make sure you app has the "manage_pages" permission for this to work.

Like this:

```
$page = $fbApi->api('/'.<page_id>,'GET',array('fields'=> 'access_token'));
$fbApi->setAccessToken($page['access_token']);
```