# Is it possible to create a Facebook event via the Graph API on behalf of a page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

[Creating Facebook event for specific page with FB Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906450/creating-facebook-event-for-specific-page-with-fb-graph-api)

There is a thread here that explains how to do this using the PHP SDK. Is it also possible to accomplish this using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the graph api it does not matter if you called it from php or js. you do the exactly the same as with php-sdk: posting to the graph-url.

```
FB.api('/graph/url', 'post', <postdata>, <callback function>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting [events was deprecated in API 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).